# SSH into virtual machine created by libvirt requires password

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization

I have created a virtual machine on my Ubuntu via `virt-install`. The image I was using is this - [Rocky-9-GenericCloud.latest.x86_64.qcow2](https://dl.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/9/images/x86_64/). `virsh list --all` shows it's running. And I have followed [Connecting to a virtual machine by using SSH](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_virtualization/assembly_connecting-to-virtual-machines_configuring-and-managing-virtualization#proc_connecting-to-a-virtual-machine-using-ssh_assembly_connecting-to-virtual-machines) to set up the SSH.

Now I can try to SSH into the VM, but it has a auth prompt to ask for my password. However, I don't recall in any steps, I have set up any passwords. What's my credential for the SSH login to my VM here?

Comment: Added the image link

Comment: Rocky Linux is not Ubuntu. I'm sure their images are nice, but we don't know anything about them.